# Why do you want to use AWS ECS vs. ElasticBeanstalk for Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm planning to use Docker, and associate 1 EC2 instance with 1 Microservice.

***Why*** do I want to deploy Docker in AWS ECS vs. ElasticBeanstalk?

It is said that AWS ECS has a native support to Docker. Is that it?

It would be great if you could be elaborate the pros and cons of running docker on *AWS ECS vs. ElasticBeanstalk*.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/4sk6a4/elastic_beanstalk_vs_ecs/

Comment: @Héctor very interesting

Answer (score 11):

Elastic Beanstalk (multi-container) is an abstraction layer on top of ECS (Elastic Container Service) with some bootstrapped features and some limitations:

- Automatically interacts with ECS and ELB
- Cluster health and metrics are readily available and displayed without any extra effort
- Load balancer must terminate HTTPS and all backend connections are HTTP
- Easily adjustable autoscaling and instance sizing
- Container logs are all collected in one place, but still segmented by instance – so in a cluster environment finding which instance served a request that logged some important data is a challenge.
- Can only set **hard memory limits** in container definitions
- All cluster instances must run the same set of containers

As of ECS IT is Amazon’s answer to container orchestration. It’s a bit rough around the edges and definitely a leap from Elastic Beanstalk, but it does have the advantage of significantly more flexibility including the ability to even define a custom scheduler.

*All of the limitations imposed by Elastic Beanstalk are lifted.*

Refer these for more info :

[Elastic Beanstalk vs. ECS vs. Kubernetes](https://fortyft.com/posts/elastic-beanstalk-vs-ecs-vs-kubernetes/)

[Amazon EC2 Container Serivce](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html)

[Amazon Elasticbeanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html)